# .htaccess запретить прямой вызов файла

Tags: .htaccess

Есть папка с видео файлами на сайте, хочу запретить прямой вызов этих файлов из браузера. Но так чтобы в плеере на сайте они все же работали.

Мб что то вроде если есть рефер с сайта то открыть доступ, хотя не уверен.

Comment: От чего защищаетесь? От размещения видео на других сайтах? От скачивания видео?

Comment: От скачивания. Хотя понятно конечно что это не поможет, просто защита от дурака.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта техника называется "защита от хотлинкинга". Но ее можно использовать и для простой защиты от скачивания. Она основана на проверке заголовка Referer и описана в [документации по mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images).

Разумеется, при желании файл все равно можно скачать, подставив свой заголовок Referer, так как этот заголовок отправляется пользователем. Либо скачать с помощью плагина. Но от простого скачивания по ссылке этот способ защищает.

В .htaccess нужно добавить правило вида:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www.example.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "\.(mp4|avi|mov)$" "-" [F,NC]
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.
Вдруг кому то еще нужно будет, добавил в начале RewriteEngine On, без включения mod_rewrite не будет работать)