# Как отключить доступ к файлам на сервере с клиентской стороны?

Tags: apache

Когда мой `.htaccess`-файл имеет это содержание

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

файлы на моем сервере я могу легко просматривать с браузера. Что очень нежелательно.

Когда же мой `.htaccess`-файл имеет такое содержание

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

файлы я уже не могу просматривать, но тогда и сайт не может подгрузить `css`-стили.

**Как я могу отключить доступ к файлам сервера для клиентской стороны так чтобы от этого не страдал сам сайт?**

Возможно пригодится (конфиги сайта)

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/reiji/Documents/native_project

        <Directory /home/reiji/Documents/native_project>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

[Ссылка](https://github.com/ReijiAkkerman/native_project.git) на сайт (вдруг пригодятся детали)

Comment: Как вы думаете, чем отличается просмотр файла и загрузка стилей? Ответ: ничем. Это одно и то же. Так что вы хотите странного.

Comment: @AlexeyTen вопрос в том что делать? Документация apache крайне скупа на примеры  и объяснения, более того в предыдущем проекте первое содержимое `.htaccess` работало, и стили подгружались и доступа к файлам сервера не было для клиента

Comment: похоже вам сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588084/htaccess-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: `.htaccess` вроде бы можно для каждой директории свой настроить... Могу ошибаться, давно Apache не поднимал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Открытые css-файлы это нормально. Зайдя на сайт `vk.com` и перейдя напрямую  по ссылке указанной в `<link>`-тэге, можно увидеть прямое тому подтверждение, файл откроется.
2. Комментарий выше от Alexey Ten. Разобрался вроде как все работает и действительно отключить доступ к css для клиента так чтобы сайт все нормально прогружал НЕВОЗМОЖНО. Исходя из первого пункта это и не нужно.